# GPT finetuning stuck at pending status in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, openai-api, chatgpt-api, fine-tuning

I'm trying to finetune GPT with some simple datasets but the finetune response status never changes from pending I have been waiting for more than a day.

this is my training data

```
training_data = [{
    "prompt": "Where is the billing ->",
    "completion": " You find the billing in the left-hand side menu.\n"
}, {
    "prompt": "How do I upgrade my account ->",
    "completion": " Visit you user settings in the left-hand side menu, then click 'upgrade account' button at the top.\n"
}]
```

Function to check the finetuning status:

```
def check_fine_tuning_status(fine_tune_id):
    response = openai.FineTune.retrieve(id=fine_tune_id)
    return response.status, response.fine_tuned_model
```

this is the response

```
{
  "object": "fine-tune",
  "id": "ft-xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "hyperparams": {
    "n_epochs": 4,
    "batch_size": null,
    "prompt_loss_weight": 0.01,
    "learning_rate_multiplier": null
  },
  "organization_id": "org-xxxxxxxxx",
  "model": "davinci",
  "training_files": [
    {
      "object": "file",
      "id": "file-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "purpose": "fine-tune",
      "filename": "file",
      "bytes": 274,
      "created_at": 1690568560,
      "status": "processed",
      "status_details": null
    }
  ],
  "validation_files": [],
  "result_files": [],
  "created_at": 1690568561,
  "updated_at": 1690568561,
  **"status": "pending",**
  "fine_tuned_model": null,
  "events": [
    {
      "object": "fine-tune-event",
      "level": "info",
      "message": "Created fine-tune: ft-xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "created_at": 1690568561
    }
  ]
}
```

and the rest of the code

```
file_name = "train00.json"

with open(file_name, "w") as output_file:
    for entry in training_data:
        json.dump(entry, output_file)
        output_file.write("\n")

print("upload res\n")

upload_response = openai.File.create(
    file=open(file_name, "rb"),
    purpose='fine-tune'
)
file_id = upload_response.id
print("fileid", file_id)

print("\nfine tune respose\n")

fine_tune_response = openai.FineTune.create(training_file=file_id, model="davinci")
fine_tune_id = fine_tune_response.id
print("fine_tune_id", fine_tune_id)

print("\n retrieve job\n")

status, fine_tuned_model_id = check_fine_tuning_status("ft-19mQUBNicpzU8eTgWjr6dzth")
while status == "pending":
    print("Fine-tuning is still in progress. Waiting...")
    time.sleep(30)  # Wait for 30 seconds before checking again
    status, fine_tuned_model_id = check_fine_tuning_status("ft-bAqHAx0MBwVVVaYcFB6wjeIl")

# Check the final status
if status == "succeeded":
    print("Fine-tuning completed successfully!")
    print("Fine-tuned model ID:", fine_tuned_model_id)
elif status == "failed":
    print("Fine-tuning failed.")
else:
    print("Unknown status:", status)
```

But I can see in my usage dashboard that finetune training request numbers are increasing, but the status is still pending state if someone could also explain what these dashboard request numbers say that will be more helpful too.
[image]
I also tried changing the security key and changing the training data models, but nothing has helped, if someone could help me to solve this it would be more helpful.

Comment: How long are you waiting for each fine-tuning request?

Comment: for the last fine-tuning request I have been waiting for more than 24 hours